# Populating db, where any record might cause exception

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-9.3

I have a large amount of data (approx 30million), packed into files of about 20K records, which I want to load into a postgresql db through a Java program. Any of these records might be broken or cause a constraint violation (less than 1%, quite negligible), which in that case I would like to simply discard the record and continue.

I have been trying to use COPY command for the speed, but the problem is that COPY discards the content of the file as soon as it finds an exception in it!!!

Then I tried to use a prepared statement with manual-commit connection, where I commit at the end of each file, but again, if I get a broken record at say location 10k, all the previous records are discarded again!

I cant use auto-commit connection, because of performance issues it will have.

Any idea how I can get this done?

Thanks

Comment: The only way to get around this is to use a `savepoint` around each `insert` statement. But that will drastically slow down the import.

Comment: Yes I read about savepoint but I was suspicious it gonna reduce the speed so didn't test it really. Was hoping to find a better solution.

Comment: You will do this more than one time? Because if not, why botter about the time it will take? Savepoint is the way I think.

Comment: are the brokren records 1% of 30 million or 1% of 20 thousand ?

Comment: how that can make a difference? its the same! its 1%

Comment: 1% of 30 million is 300 thousand so most of the 15 thousand files could be expected to contain errors

Comment: arrgh, 15 hundered files

Answer (score 1):

One option perhaps is to copy the data into a table that has no constraints and then process that data to remove the infringing records before either adding the constraints or copying the data into the live table.

most types of constraints be be assessed using SQL.